# TiB, not TB, Seriously?

Tags: code-golf, conversion

If you're like me (and/or use Windows), You should have found this issue quite disturbing.

You plug in a hard drive (2TB for my occasion), and realize it doesn't show as 2TB, but a bit smaller size which is clearly not 2TB.

Over some research, I found it was because of Microsoft's mistake. Mistyping [Binary prefix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) as Decimal prefixes. (i.e. They typed 1TiB as 1TB)

So, I would like to see a Binary prefix to Decimal prefix program. Since this is a big problem (and some computers are literally toasters), You have to make your program as short as possible.

[<sup>conversion chart I found</sup>](http://www.smartconversion.com/unit_conversion/prefix_conversion_table.aspx)

---

## I/O

You will be given the size (positive real number, will not exceed 2ˆ16 when converted), and the unit (4 of them, KiB, MiB, GiB and TiB, each corresponds to 1024ˆ1, 1024ˆ2, 1024ˆ3 and 1024ˆ4 bytes)

You have to output the (decimal representation of) the size (rounded half-up to integer value), and the corresponding unit.

---

## Examples

```
678 MiB => 711 MB
1.8 TiB => 2 TB
```

**Tip: Google has a unit converter**

Comment: This needs more specification. What units do we have to handle? What number ranges? With what precision?

Comment: @xnor precision is specified(rounded half-up to integer value), everything else is edited to specify

Comment: Better, but there's more to specify. How much precision can the inputs be given with? Can they be negative? Can an input be given like `.15`? `1.00`? What about outputs? There's a bunch of things like this to pin down. I'd suggest moving it to the sandbox.

Comment: Rounding an precision are different. You use fractional terabytes but entire megabytes in your examples.

Comment: @Dennis Huh? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Why is the first output 711 MB and not 710.9 MB?

Comment: @Dennis specified: rounded half-up to integer value

Comment: So the output for 1.4 TiB would be 2 TB?

Comment: @Dennis Yup. 1.4 TiB=> 1.5...TB => 2TB.

Comment: What would the output for 999 MiB be?

Comment: @Dennis 1048 it is.

Comment: TiB or not TiB, that is the question.

Comment: @SIGSEGV So we don't have to "jump" prefixes? You should clarify that in the challenge spec.

Comment: Calling the discrepancy "*Microsoft's* horrible *mistake*" is somewhat flamebait. All they're doing is maintaining backwards compatibility with what us old-timers (read: anyone in their 30s or up) grew up knowing as the standard.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anyone who actually calls 1024 bytes a "kibibyte". You read it Kilobytes. The existence of a decimal form/prefix at all is the real problem

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.6, <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```
a,b=input().split()
print(f'{eval(a)*1.024**" KMGT".find(b[0]):.0f} {b[0]}B')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 35 Bytes

```
=H@z_3s[.E*v<4z^1.024x" KMGT"HdH\B
```

Adding the unit to the output costed me quite some bytes.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DH%40z_3s%5B.E%2av%3C4z%5E1.024x%22+KMGT%22HdH%5CB&input=1.8+TiB&test_suite_input=678+MiB%0A1.8+TiB&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

Prompts for unit and size, and outputs unit and size.

```apl
⌊.5+⎕×1.024*'KMGT'⍳⊃⎕←⍞∩⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9TRnvb/UU@Xnqn2o76ph6cb6hkYmWipe/u6h6g/6t38qKsZKPyobcKj3nmPOlYC2Y7/H3W0/0/j8s104jIzt@BK4woBsgz1LAA)

`∩⎕A` intersection with uppercase **A**lphabet of

`⍞` character input (unit) from STDIN

`⎕←` output that to STDOUT

`⊃` get the first character of the outputted value

`'KMGT'⍳` find the 1-based index of that in this string

`1.024*` raise this number that that power

`⎕×` multiply numeric input from STDIN with that

`.5+` add a half to that

`⌊` round that down

Comment: It should be 1.024 not 1.044 in your explanation

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Indeed. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 63 bytes

```php
<?=1.024**strpos(_KMGT,($m=$argv[2][0]))*$argv[1]+.5|0," $m",B;
```

takes input from command line arguments;
run with `echo '<code>' | php -n` or save to file and run with `php -n <filename>`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <del>44</del> 43 bytes

It has a built-in function for everything

```
Round@UnitConvert[#,StringPart[#,-3]<>"B"]&
```

(Input should be a string `"678 MiB"`.)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

```js
f=
(s,[n,[u]]=s.split` `)=>(n*1.024**` KMGT`.search(u)).toFixed()+` ${u}B`
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=/\s[KMGT]/.test(this.value)?f(this.value):``><span id=o>
```